# how to get inventory_hostanme and ansible_ssh_hosts info by running playbook on localhost

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I want to write hostname and ssh_host under a specific group from an inventory file to a file in my localhost.
I have tried this:

**my_role**

```
  set_fact:
    hosts: "{{ hosts_list|default({}) | combine( {inventory_hostname: ansible_ssh_host} ) }}"
  when: "'my_group' in group_names"
```

**Playbook**

```
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - my_role
```

But now if i try to write this to a file in another task, it will create a file for the hosts in inventory file.

Can you please suggest if there is a better way to create a file containing dictionary with inventory_hostname and ansible_ssh_host as key and value respectively, by running playbook on localhost.

Comment: FYI, "Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from ansible_ssh_user, ansible_ssh_host, and ansible_ssh_port to become ansible_user, ansible_host, and ansible_port. If you are using a version of Ansible prior to 2.0, you should continue using the older style variables (ansible_ssh_*). These shorter variables are ignored, without warning, in older versions of Ansible." See [Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) and [delegate_to](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) localhost.

```
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_inventory_hostname: "{{ ansible_host }}"
    - tempfile:
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: result
    - lineinfile:
        path: "{{ result.path }}"
        line: "inventory_hostname: {{ my_inventory_hostname }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
    - debug:
        msg: "inventory_hostname: {{ ansible_host }}
              stored in {{ result.path }}"
```

Note: There is no need to quote the conditions. Conditions are expanded by default.

```
when: my_group in group_names
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great. 
Also, I am trying to get ansible_host belonging to specific group in inventory, by adding:
 ```when: "my_group' in group_names" 
```
under -set_fact, but that gives me error for hosts which do not belong to the group.
Is there a way to skip undefined variables to be written to lineinfile

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer@Vladimir Botka

I came up with another requirement to write the hosts belonging to a certain group to a file, below code can help with that (adding to @Vladimir's solution).

```
- hosts: all
  become: no
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_inventory_hostname: "{{ ansible_host }}"
   - lineinfile:
        path: temp/hosts
        line: "inventory_hostname: {{ my_inventory_hostname }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['my_group']
      delegate_to: localhost
    - debug:
        msg: "inventory_hostname: {{ ansible_host }}"
```